# Gazebo classic or Ignition for a new plugin?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I'm going to design a new multi-sensors plugin (stereo camera with IMU and Magnetometer) that should work outside ROS and also in ROS/ROS2.
Do you suggest starting from the classic Gazebo or moving directly to Ignition?

All the documentation that I found is for the classic Gazebo, but I have the doubt to release something new that is already obsolete.

Best regards,
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28168/gazebo-classic-or-ignition-for-a-new-plugin?/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87579/myzhar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't know what do you want exactly. Classic Gazebo will be at EOL on 2025. Personally, I joined Gazebo community when Citadel comes out and I've been using Citadel+ rest of my career. I find them extremely useful. I had a short experience with the classic gazebo. I'd prefer new Gazebo over classic Gazebo. Again, that's just me which is a little biased ;P

I believe ign has stereo camera with IMU. Magnetometer....I'm not sure, but I think you might want to think outside of the box using that. For example, I used three cameras to act like 3 IR (Infrared sensors) sensor.

I don't have any good answers for Magnetomemter, sorry! I guess your question is actually for yourself. Are you willing to start over with new Gazebo once Classic Gazebo is at EOL?

EDIT 05/27/22:
FOUND! Magnetometer is here: https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/foxy/ros_ign_gazebo_demos

---

Originally posted by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) with karma: 87 on 2022-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0